# How to deal with Umalut character files in a condition statements in shell scripting

Tags: shell, special-characters

My Script will perform some validation, copy and move the files to destination folders but the script is not working when we have Umlaut character files.

grep, cat,cp, lsof and for conditions are not interpreting properly while executing the script. PF below scenarios for the reference.

**Vermögensausweis**  it's diplaying as below

for t in '"$FILELIST"'
cp -p $'/opt/DOC04/input/2019-11-01_**********Verm\366gensausweis_per****************.9887768769.pdf'

cat $'./22019-11-01_**********Verm\303\266gensausweis_per****************.9887768769.pdf.inp'

lsof $'/opt/DOC04/input/2019-11-01_**********Verm\366gensausweis_per****************.9887768769.pdf'

grep '^F' $'././22019-11-01_**********Verm\303\266gensausweis_per****************.9887768769.pdf.inp'

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)  your code properly. Also, show us your locale (command: `locale`). And: What do you mean by _not interpreting properly_?

Comment: Why do you use `$'`? Is there a `do` missing? `for t in '"$FILELIST"'` Why do you want to iterate over a single parameter? `but the script is not working` Is the script even executing without syntax errors? How do you know it's not working? Do you get any error messages? What messages do you get? Could you please post them as text verbatim in your question? Does the script work without umlaut characters? How does it work without them? What exactly changes? Why not just `cp "Vermögensausweis" "somewhere"`?

Comment: Please include the error message output from `grep`, `cat`, *etc.*

Comment: Try pasting your code into http://shellcheck.net for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

```
for t in '"$FILELIST"'
```

...because `$t` won't be a list, it'd be a literal.  Demo:

```
FILELIST="'foo~* bar' baz"
for t in '"$FILELIST"' ; do echo "$t" ; done
```

Output, is not a list, it's a literal:

```
"$FILELIST"
```

The problem is that a regular variable is not a good choice to hold an array with quoted metacharacters.  For regular shell script, using `set --` and `"${@}"` should work:

```
set -- 'foo~* bar' baz ; for t in "${@}" ; do echo "$t" ; done
```

Output:

```
foo~* bar
baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply

script is working fine for other files without special characters(umlaut). we are facing issue when the files are with umlaut characters. copied partial script. if you want I can post the script.

Below lines are the verbose output of the script.

cp -p $'/opt/DOC04/input/2019-11-01_**********Verm\366gensausweis_per****************.9887768769.pdf'

cat $'./22019-11-01_**********Verm\303\266gensausweis_per****************.9887768769.pdf.inp'

lsof $'/opt/DOC04/input/2019-11-01_**********Verm\366gensausweis_per****************.9887768769.pdf'

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer so it is in the wrong place. Please copy this information, click `edit` under your original question and paste it in there. Then delete this *"non-answer"*. Thank you.